# Swift 4.0 cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSLayoutConstraint' with an argument list of type '(NSLayoutConstraint)'

Tags: ios, ios11, swift4, xcode9

I am using XCode Version 9.0 (9A235), macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 (16G29),  iOS 11.0.

I need to add constraint into array and then later I need to activate it.

For doing this I did like...

```
// 1.Declare and initialized  the constraint

private lazy var labelConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

// 2.Prepare constraint   
let widthConstraint = 
    headerLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: licenseLabel.widthAnchor)

// 3.Constraint added into the array   
labelConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(widthConstraint))

// 4.Finally activate the constraints   
labelConstraints.activate()
```

After build my xcode project it throws an error like

```
ERROR: **cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSLayoutConstraint' with an argument list of type '(NSLayoutConstraint)'** 

**labelConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(widthConstraint))**
```

Comment: Please try to format your question better in the future. Don't start it with a `-` because that makes stackoverflow treat it as a list item. Indent code snippets by an extra four spaces. I have fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is here:

```
labelConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(widthConstraint))
```

Your `widthConstraint` variable is already an `NSLayoutConstraint`, so you don't need to try to convert it to an `NSLayoutConstraint`. Just do this:

```
labelConstraints.append(widthConstraint)
```

Your second problem is here:

```
labelConstraints.activate()
```

Type `Array` doesn't have an `activate` method. You can activate all constraints in `labelConstraints` like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(labelConstraints)
```

Comment: Thank you @rob mayoff.

Now I successfully added into array and also logged the labelConstraints.count it reurns some X  value. But it crashing my project and thows a console error like :
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMapTable nsli_superitem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe4b44ecf00'

Comment: You will have to edit your question to include more details.

Comment: Thank you @rob mayoff.
Its working now. Actually the above error is not related to this, its another one.